# Преобразование вывода fetchall pymysql в int..?

Tags: python, sql, discord, discord.py, pymysql

Возникла проблема, связанная с получением данных из mysql. Мне необходимо, чтобы моя программа(бот) получала списки тех, кто владеет ботом. Но моя программа не может получить данные из бд. Я подразумеваю, что проблема в словаре, который выводит непонятное для моей программы. Надеюсь, что вы мне поможете исправить данное недоразумение

Код:

```py
import pymysql.cursors
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

db = pymysql.connect(host='**************',
                     port=25*****,
                     user='***',
                     password='**************',
                     database='*******')

with db.cursor() as cursor:
    # Read a single record
    sql = ("select `id` from `owners`")
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchall() #<----- Получение данных из курсора в переменную

class owner(commands.Cog, name="owner"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name="shutdown")
    async def shutdown(self, context, message):
        if context.message.author.id == result: #<--------- Тут идет получение данных из переменной
            embed = discord.Embed(
                description="Выключаюсь! :wave:",
                color=0x42F56C
            )
            await context.send(embed=embed)
            await self.bot.close()
            await message.channel.send('ок')
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="Ошибка!",
                description="У вас недостаточно прав для выполнения данной команды",
                color=0xE02B2B
            )
            await context.send(embed=embed)
```

Заранее спасибо!

P.S - Я новичок, и немного не понимаю как это преобразовать. Я пробовал, но к сожалению я смог получить только один id владельца, вместо двух

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы берете все значения которые лежат у вас в БД, то вы получаете на выходе [кортеж](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/kortezhi-tuple.html) (вот так он будет выглядеть, если вы с БД возьмете больше чем одно значение рядка: `[[15448481818, 1881811818, 1518118181], [19191911, 619198198189, 189191981],]` если только одне, то `[[19191191, 14811816],]`) что бы достать с него определенное значения ва надо взять ячейку:

```
for i in range(len(result)):
    if context.message.author.id == result[i]['id']:
        ...
```

Comment: нет, оно выводится как id: 123456.....

Тут наверное уже можно сделать replace?

Comment: Можете сделать `print(result)` и скинуть то что оно выводит?

Comment: Консоль выдает следующее (ID зашифрованы): [{'id': 4099265*********}, {'id': 41871270**********}]

Comment: @kavo, тогда вам надо пройти циклом, сейчас изменю ответ

Comment: @kavo, также вы можете проверить что вы одержите вот таким кодом:
`for i in range(len(result)):    print(result[i]['id'])`

Comment: Ничего хорошего 

`if context.message.author.id == result[0]['id']:
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Тогда циклом додайте значения в новый массив и потом проверяйте через этот массив

Comment: А, все сработало. Извиняюсь, видимо я как то успел потерять ```cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor```, пока редактировал код под ваш ответ. Спасибо!